# bash syntax error on if statement with grep

Tags: linux, bash

I'm getting a syntax error on line 7 when `i` is equal to 0 (and `if` is  supposed to fail). If I use it on files where `grep` succeeds and `i` is not 0 the program works.

What could be the problem?

```
#!/bin/bash

function search_author_tests {
    while read line; do
        i=`grep -c "commit version: "$line"" "$1"/QA/*.tst`
        echo $i
        if (($i>0)); then
            echo -n $line 
            grep "result" `grep -wl "commit version: "$line"" "$1"/QA/*.tst`|cut -d ":" -f2
        fi  
    done
}   


grep -w "$2" "$1"/*.comp | cut -d" " -f2 | sort -n| search_author_tests $1
```

example error: 
 line 7: ((: /u1/044/adaramir/mtm/ex1/q3/test3/cv/QA/1.tst:1
/u1/044/adaramir/mtm/ex1/q3/test3/cv/QA/2.tst:0>0: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "/u1/044/adaramir/mtm/ex1/q3/test3/cv/QA/1.tst:1
/u1/044/adaramir/mtm/ex1/q3/test3/cv/QA/2.tst:0>0")

Comment: What syntax error are you getting? You should probably also run this code through http://www.shellcheck.net/ and correct the things it shows you.

Comment: This may not be *the* problem, but -- you need to change `"commit version: "$line""` to just `"commit version: $line"`. As it is, you're not actually protecting `$line` from filename-expansion and word-splitting.

Answer (score 0):

You are grepping from several files, and you see the count per file.
Change your assignment on line 7 into

```
i=$(cat "$1"/QA/*.tst 2>/dev/null | grep -c "commit version: $line")
```

Answer (score 0):

when "grep -c" is used with multiple files its output is of form:

```
<file1>:<count1>
<file2>:<count2>
```

solutions:
1. Either speicify single file instead of *.txt

2. change

   #!/bin/bash

   ```
   function search_author_tests {
       while read line; do
           i=`grep -c "commit version: "$line"" "$1"/QA/*.tst | cut -d: -f2 | sort -nr | head -1`
           echo $i
           if (($i>0)); then
               echo -n $line 
               grep "result" `grep -wl "commit version: "$line"" "$1"/QA/*.tst`|cut -d ":" -f2
           fi  
       done
   }   


   grep -w "$2" "$1"/*.comp | cut -d" " -f2 | sort -n| search_author_tests $1
   ```

Thanks